# How to setup a VPS with Django, Nginx, Gunicorn, Postgres and then properly deploy a Django application to it?

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, linode

Perhaps there is a definitive tutorial or blog describing what I'm looking for, but I haven't seen it.  And being new to Django, I'm really looking for a proper way to **both** set up a VPS **and** deploy the project to it ... the latter in a repeatable/sensible way as the project evolves.

Here is what my project looks like:

1. Using Django 1.6.2 + Postgres
2. Project structure is essentially what is described [here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)
3. Static assets delivered locally in development need to be uploaded/delivered from S3 in production
4. My VPS is a basic Linode running Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say [Test-Driven Web Development with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/index.html) is a good one. It's mostly focused on TDD, but it's really good at covering the basics of Django as well. Chapter 8 talks about deployment and is pretty thorough.

EDIT:

Saw that that book doesn't use S3 for static files, so I'd recommend [this blog post](http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/07/14/using-amazon-s3-to-host-your-django-static-files/) for dealing with that.

Answer (score 1):

This article: [How To Install and Configure Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn) has some great instruction on getting the VPS setup, minus the S3 assets.
For repeatable deployment do some research on [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).